# Relocalising in a previously saved point cloud

Tags: unity-game-engine, point-clouds, arcore

I am currently working on indoor navigation app with ARcore. I would like to do something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOMysKbDNxk) but due to constraints of my school project, I have to work on Android and thus cannot use Placenote. Therefore, I wanted to try to do something similar using point clouds. I have tried to save the point clouds and would like to ask if it is possible to relocalise in it later on? Else, would it be possible to use it like a marker?

Thank you!

Comment: I dont think point cloud would be reliable you can use `cloudAnchors` but it can only be stored for 24 hours. You can check these [guys](https://fantasmo.io/home) for indoor navigation but their SDK is still in beta and only available for ARKit.

Comment: @AliKanat Thank you for your reply! I would like to do something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOMysKbDNxk) but due to constraints of my school project, I have to work on Android and thus cannot use Placenote. Therefore, I wanted to try to do something similar using point clouds. If point cloud would not be reliable, is there any workaround for it? I thought of using `cloudAnchors` but from what I have found, there don't seem to be a way to store it locally (please correct me if I'm wrong). Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated! Thank you! (Sorry I'm really new to this!)

Comment: Well good thing about cloud anchors is you can resolve them using ARCore and you do not have to do the math behind it. I am not quite sure about the math behind it but from the video i can say you can definitely handle  dropping waypoints in local by logging these anchors into a file and reading it again in another Session. However, coordinate system changes everytime you run the app so you have to come up with a solution to use these anchors in each Session. i would recommend taking a look at [rigid transform](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671) and using an Augmented Image in mapping Session.

Comment: However, this wont be an easy implementation. You need to find a Transformation matrix by comparing 3 points from each coordinate system in order to find way points' location in each Session. So i would recommend starting with this. I have a rigid transform implementation for Unity [here](https://github.com/alikanat001/RigidTransform) if you want to take a look at it. Of course it is just a prototype.

Comment: @AliKanat May I clarify what do you mean by using an Augmented Image in mapping Session?

Comment: To be able calculate a Transformation matrix between two coordinate systems, you need at least 3 points which are common in both. That is why i suggested you to use Augmented Image. You can calculate the coordinate of corners of the image and use it in calculation.

Comment: @AliKanat Thank you for your reply! If I were to use Augmented Image to calculate a Transformation matrix between two coordinate systems, does it mean that I have to place an Augmented Image at all the locations where the user can localise in?

Answer (score 0):

Since the comments are getting too long i wanted to post an answer to express what i am thinking for the problem in General.

Main problem with ARCore and scanning a room or installing a set-up in a room  is storage and resolving the anchors used in earlier Sessions. [Cloud anchors](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/cloud-anchors/developer-guide-unity) can solve both these problems for you but your anchors can be stored only for 24 hours.

Another issue in OP's case is ARCore changes its coordinate system every time the app launched. So relative to your device right hand side is `+x` , upper hand side is `+y` and the direction your phone is facing is `+z`. Therefore, in order to achieve what is done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOMysKbDNxk), you need to **anchor** these way points and store these anchors locally in scanning phase of your application. Then in another  `Session` you need to have these way points located at the same physical location. In order to do that you need to have a Transformation between scan phase coordinate system and new `Session` coordinate system considering ARCore changes coordinate system in every `Session`.

In order to solve this my suggestion would be using an Augmented Image located at a location of the room. This image will be used for calculating the Transformation matrix between two coordinate system. In scanning phase you have to track the image and log 
3 positions from the image(e.g center, upper left and lower left) along with positions of your anchor. Then when a user wants to use indoor navigation, he/she has to track the image first then you calculate the Transformation matrix using **same 3 points** again in a different coordinate system. You can use Rigid Transform for this task.

Once you have found the Transformation Matrix you can position way points again in the same physical location in real world (but don't forget they will have different coordinates in Unity). After that you can implement your navigation using these anchors.
You can also use more Augmented Image to increase precision as long as you have **3 common points in both coordinate system**.